MySQL: Select number of students that attended a specific class
I have n students in my class and I see them 22 days in a school year. I'd like to know for every class how many students attended each day.
For this I have a table named classes which has the following fields:
class_id, class_date
I have a students table with the following fields:
student_id, student_name
Then I have a table that keeps track of the students presence at each class called class_mgmt:
cm_ID, cm_class, cm_student, cm_student_present (1 OR 0)
What I am trying to wrap my head around is how to generate a result like this
on class of date 2024-06-30 there were 23/25 students present, 2024-06-15 there were 25/25 students present, 2024-06-01 there were 20/25 students present, etc.
Any thoughts on the correct query to return the above?
The nearest I got was:
SELECT `class_id`, `class_date`, count(`cm_student_present`) as student_present 
FROM `class_mgmt` 
JOIN `classes` ON `cm_class` = `class_id` 
WHERE `cm_student_present`=1 
GROUP BY `class_ID`;

But that obviously doesn't do the trick, especially since it omits all the classes where nobody showed up

It's kind of hard to help you without some example data. You can probably do something like SUM(cm_student_present) to count the attendees and COUNT(cm_student_present)to count the possible number of students, then GROUP BY class_ID, class_date. But it's hard to verify without sample data.

That;s exactly it! Many thanks.

SELECT 
    c.class_id,
    c.class_date,
    COUNT(cm.cm_student_present) AS students_present,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM students) AS total_students
FROM 
    classes c
LEFT JOIN 
    class_mgmt cm ON c.class_id = cm.cm_class AND cm.cm_student_present = 1
GROUP BY 
    c.class_id, c.class_date
ORDER BY 
    c.class_date;

